# Dúvida para estruturação de banco - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, modelo-relacional, integração

Boa noite!

Gostaria de pedir ajuda para ter algumas ideias, vou explicar mais ou menos o que gostaria:

Digamos que eu tenha dois banco de dados, um para servir como Central (recebe a informações de vários outros banco de dados), e outro que recebe a informação do sistema, e envia para o banco Central.

Certo, o que pode acontecer é de o banco local não enviar alguma informação para o banco central, e com isso ficar com alguma lacuna. O que gostaria de fazer é uma "verificação" da quantidade de informação entre os dois bancos.

O que pensei em fazer:

- Criar uma tabela no banco central, com a informação da quantidade de informações do banco local, central e a qual tabela está sendo verificada. Certo, a ideia era criar uma Procedure para verificar quando houvesse divergência, e então enviar uma solicitação para o banco local tentar a subir a informação faltando, minha dúvida seria, como eu poderia informar especificamente qual a informação que está faltando? Teriam dicas para estruturar melhor?

Na primeira imagem seria um exemplo de informações, e como elas podem estar divergente. Na segunda como seria a estrutura básica da tabela para verificar.

O problema é que muitas tabelas não seguem um padrão sequencial numérico (muitas possuem algumas colunas como PK). Pensei em criar uma outra coluna na tabela para deixar a soma total de algo, e com isso, validar qual o valor que está faltando (no exemplo, seria somado o (1,2,4), resultando em 7, e iria comparar com a soma do banco local que seria 10, com isso pegaria a diferença e enviaria a solicitação ao banco local para enviar a informação do valor divergente.

[image: Demonstração]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que você não usa as próprias funções de replicação do banco? Parece que está tentando reinventar a roda.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15